# How to catch EVERY exception in C++/Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, dll-injection

I have a DLL that's being injected into very old, buggy and now unsupported by it's developer application. Sometimes that application crashes, and I need some way to catch literally all unhandled exceptions (from DLL) that may occur to save data and only then allow the app to crash. How can I achieve that?

For now, there is an external debugger for that purpose, but it's just too slow and also buggy to keep it that way.

Comment: Sorry, just found solution to this. [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634.aspx) is what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

You have to start a new process which hosts the DLL. If the DLL is going to crash, it's going to bring down the process, whether you like it or not. Sure, you could attempt to catch an exception or something like that, but if the exception is being thrown, that means memory is corrupted. [It is better to crash catastrophically than to have the program continuing to run in an inconsistent state.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)

The windows shell is a program which actually does this -- it launches some plugins in a surrogate process, so that if the plugin crashes, it doesn't bring down the whole shell. You'd need to use interprocess communication to communicate between yourself and the surrogate you start.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to make main application save data before crashing, not prevent it from crash.

Comment: @uber: "Saving data" is "continuing to run" -- how do you know the crashed component hasn't destroyed the very data you want to save? (A wild pointer can overwrite your own data, after all) Your users will certainly not be happy when they find out that whatever crashed your program has now destroyed their work on disk.

Comment: work being destroyed is never a good thing, whether it's on disk or in memory. You'd like to save as much as possible. There are two easy techniques here: save early, save often, and do not save that working copy over the original document.